# Does Zonya's Hourglass cancel spells that are travelling?

Tags: league-of-legends

If a Viegar casts his full combo on, say, a Kennen, but Kennen uses Zonya's Hourglass before the spells reach him (while the spells are still travelling), will Kennen take any damage from the spells?

Answer (score 1):

Zhona's will cancel anything that hit the person while it is active.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will block the damage after a spell has been casted, that it why they have projectile speed variations.